# Очередь доступа в QThread

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qthread, pyqt6

Задача простая - создаем сцену, на нее добавляем объекты (~400к+шт). 
Объекты должны изменять свои параметры в режиме реального времени, но делать расчеты новых параметров в основном потоке никак нельзя, так как сцена будет тормозить. 
Расчеты нужно производить в другом потоке (желательно каждые 100мс) и там же обновлять параметры объектов, а основной поток сцены должен продолжать рисовать объекты.

Код:

```
class CalcThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, scene: QGraphicsScene = None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)

        self.scene = scene

    def run(self):

        while True:
           
            #  Долгие расчеты новых параметров для объектов сцены..
            self.scene.update(self.scene.views()[0].mapToScene(self.scene.views()[0].rect()).boundingRect())
            print(self.scene.views()[0].rect(), len(self.scene.items()))
            time.sleep(1)


class Widget_GraphSurface(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mainScene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.mainScene.addItem(добавляем много объектов....)
        self.ggv_main = QGraphicsView(self.mainScene)

        mThread = QThread()
        cThread = CalcThread(None, self.mainScene)
        cThread.moveToThread(mThread)
        cThread.start()
```

Если запустить в таком виде, вроде бы в методе `run`, потока `CalcThread`, все работает как нужно, а именно - он блокирует доступ к `mainScene` основному потоку, пока проводит расчеты. Но сцена начинает сильно тормозить, вроде все логично, основной поток не может получить `self.mainscene` пока она занята в `CalcThread`. Я так полагаю, что управление `self.mainscene`, возвращается после каждой завершенной итерации метода `run` из `CalcThread`.
Задача все же состоит в том, чтобы сделать незаметными расчеты, чтобы сцена продолжала плавно рисовать элементы.
Были предприняты попытки:

1. Делать расчеты в обычном потоке `threading.Thread` - все летало, до того момента, как поток из `threading.Thread` и `MainThread`(основной поток сцены), пытались получить доступ к сцене одновременно - получаем аксес виолайшн
2. Метод 1 + использование `Lock`, `RLock`, семафоры и т.д. - итог один аксес виолейшн
3. Передача в поток `CalcThread` напрямую всего экземпляра класса со сценой и вызов из него функции расчетов - итог - аксес виолешн
4. Метод 3 + кьютишные мютексы и локи - аксес виолейшн

Итого: лучше всего на данный момент работает, если расчеты делать в том же потоке, где и сцена, но картинка подтормаживает, а хочется, наоборот. Возникает несколько вопросов:

1. Я не правильно использую `QThread`, что нужно исправить?
2. Может нужно использовать кьютишные мютексы в потоке `CalcThread`?
3. Может нужно организовать очередь доступа к объекту сцены?
4. Нужен другой подход к этому вопросу?

По сути мне нужно:

1. В потоке `CalcThread` получить сцену
2. Получить некоторые объекты со сцены
3. Получить параметры сцены и этих объектов
4. Отдать управление сценой обратно в `MainThread`
5. Произвести расчеты
6. Снова получить сцену в потоке `CalcThread`
7. Изменить параметры объектов на сцене
8. Отдать сцену обратно в `MainThread`

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен, что правильно понимаю то, что вы хотите сделать. Но мне кажется, что это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.Qt import *


r = lambda : random.randint(0, 255)
r255 = lambda : (r(), r(), r())


class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # (добавляем много объектов....)
        for i in range(400):
            item = QGraphicsEllipseItem()
            item.setRect(0, 0, r(), r())
            item.setBrush(QColor(*r255()))
            item.setPos(r()*5, r()*5)
            self.addItem(item)


class CalcThread(QThread):
    change_r = pyqtSignal(int, object)
   
    def __init__(self, _items, parent=None):
        super(CalcThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self._items = _items

    def run(self):
        while True:
            #  Долгие расчеты новых параметров для объектов сцены..
            for i in range(1, self._items):
                r = lambda : random.randint(0, 255)
                self.change_r.emit(i, r)
                self.msleep(100)


class Widget_GraphSurface(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1000, 600)

        self.mainScene = Scene()                    
        
        pixmap = QPixmap("hand128.png")
        pixmap_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
        pixmap_item.setFlags(
            pixmap_item.flags()
            | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable
            | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
        )
        pixmap_item.setPos(700, 700)    
        self.mainScene.addItem(pixmap_item) 
        
        self.ggv_main = QGraphicsView(self.mainScene)
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.ggv_main, 0, 0)        

        _items = len(self.mainScene.items())
        self.mThread = CalcThread(_items)
        self.mThread.change_r.connect(self.change_item)
        self.mThread.start()

    def change_item(self, i, r):
        item = self.mainScene.items()[i]
        item.setRect(0, 0, r(), r())
        item.setPos(r()*7, r()*7)        
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget_GraphSurface()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**hand128.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, сложно объяснить конкретно, но попробую, вы на правильном пути были. Мне необходимо в методе `run` потока `CalcThread` обращаться к объектам сцены, не ко всем, а те, что в поле видимости `QGraphicsView`. Попробуйте передать сцену в поток и обратиться в методе `run` хотя бы к параметрам сцены: `self.mainScene.sceneRect()` , ну или получить все элементы сцены в зоне видимости `QGraphicsView` - `for item in self.ggv_main.items(self.ggv_main.rect()):` - будет аксесс виолейшн, как обойти это я не знаю(